# What is currently the best way to get a favicon to display in all browsers that support Favicons?

Tags: html, standards, favicon

What is currently the best way to get a favicon to display in all browsers that currently support it?

Please include:

1. Which image formats are supported by which browsers.
2. Which lines are needed in what places for the various browsers.

Comment: It might also be worth including the 'favicons' for the iPhone here as well; that is if the user chooses to add your website to their home screen. The code used in this case is as follows: <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch.png" /> The dimensions should be 57x57 pixels. Alternatively you can omit the link tag and just put a file called 'apple-touch-icon.png' in the root directory of your website.

Comment: While you're at it, read this: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/touch-icons

Comment: Note that you'll need larger icons for iPad and retina iPhone displays. See Apple's guidelines: http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

Answer (score 110, accepted):

I go for a belt and braces approach here.

I create a 32x32 icon in both the `.ico` and `.png` formats called `favicon.ico` and `favicon.png`. The icon name doesn't really matter unless you are dealing with older browsers.

1. Place `favicon.ico` at your site root to support the older browsers (optional and only relevant for older browsers.
2. Place favicon.png in my images sub-directory (just to keep things tidy).
3. Add the following HTML inside the `<head>` element.

```
<link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.png" type="image/png" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

Please note that:

- The MIME type for `.ico` files was registered as image/vnd.microsoft.icon by the [**IANA**](http://www.iana.org).
- Internet Explorer will ignore the `type` attribute for the shortcut icon relationship and this is the only browser to support this relationship, it doesn't need to be supplied.

[**Reference**](http://www.jonathantneal.com/blog/understand-the-favicon/)

Comment: OK, I'm having a 'Microsoft is getting on my nerves' day. I can't get this to work in Internet Explorer, despite the fact that it shows the favicon for the stackoverflow site. Are there any other settings that affect this, such as doctype?

Comment: FYI - I found the answer. 
If you refer to the site via http://localhost:8080/index.html , it doesn't work - if you use the actual name of the machine (http://machineName:8080/index.html) everything functions as you'd expect.
I can't even begin to understand this behaviour - anybody care to try?

Comment: Update - the behaviour is caused by the browser caching the icon. Clearing the temporary internet files will cure this, if you feel happy losing your cache.

Comment: Would it be neater to put the IE version of the link in an IE conditional comment?

Comment: 32x32?? Isn't 16x16 the norm?

Comment: If anyone is having trouble with this on their test systems ensure that the path "/images/favicon.png" is correct remember the "/" at the start makes it the root of the domain so if your file is in "http:/ /testpc/site1/default.htm" and the image at "http:/ /testpc/site1/images/favicon.png" remove that first "/" ;)

Comment: @EoghanM indeed, but the catch is that conditional comments are version specific : heavy to set, and painful to maintain.

Answer (score 10):

I use .ico format and put the following two lines within the `<head>` element:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Answer (score 6):

To also support touch icons for tablets and smartphones I prefer the approach of [HTML5Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/src/doc/html.md#favicons-and-touch-icon)

More information on touch icons can be found in [this article](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/touch-icons).

With the current status of browser-support you don't even have to add the HTML tag for the favicon in your document. The browsers will search automaticly a list of files, see this example for iOS:

> If no icons are specified in the HTML, iOS Safari will search the
>   website’s root directory for icons with the apple-touch-icon or
>   apple-touch-icon-precomposed prefix. For example, if the appropriate
>   icon size for the device is 57 × 57 pixels, iOS searches for filenames
>   in the following order:
>
> 1. apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png
> 2. apple-touch-icon-57x57.png
> 3. apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
> 4. apple-touch-icon.png

My advise is to not include a favicon in your document, but have a list of files ready in the root website:

- apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png
- apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png
- apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png
- apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png
- apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
- apple-touch-icon.png `(57px*57px)`
- favicon.ico `HiDPI (32x32px)`

When you download a template from [html5boilerplate.com](http://html5boilerplate.com/) these are all included, you just have to replace them with your own icons.

Comment: First link is outdated, needs to go to https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/src/doc/html.md#favicons-and-touch-icon now. I'd edit myself but it's not enough characters changed :/ Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 5):

[Wikipedia to the rescue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)

Answer (score 4):

IE6 cannot handle PNGs correctly, be warned.

Answer (score 3):

Favicon must be an [.ico file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28icon_image_file_format%29) to work properly on all browsers.

Modern browsers also support PNG and GIF images.

I've found that in general the easiest way to create one is to use a freely available web service such as [favicon.cc](http://favicon.cc/).

Answer (score 3):

There is also a site where you can check how the favicon of any page is made

[getfavicon.org](http://www.getfavicon.org)

There you can see a tutorial about making favicons, image types and resolutions, it's nice!

Comment: No longer operational.

Answer (score 2):

Having a `favicon.*` in your root directory is automatically detected by most browsers. You can ensure it's detected by using:

```
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/path/image.png" />
```

Personally I use .png images but most formats should work.

Comment: No, it's not "favicon.*", only very few formats work: ico, png, gif, jpeg and SVG. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#File_format_support.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question has become [complicated enough](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48969053/7343159) that the best way is to just use a tool like RealFaviconGenerator, which lets you upload a png/jpg and then generates favicons and code to cover all the platforms for you: https://realfavicongenerator.net/