# how to insert special fav icon bar on the web

Tags: firefox

Is it possible to insert special icon bar on the web like [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox) (show icon front of address bar from firefox 3.0)
How do it?

Thanks

eBattulga

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073/what-is-currently-the-best-way-to-get-a-favicon-to-display-in-all-browsers-that-s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about the **Security ID** button located in the address bar:

[image: Security Id]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.com](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/img/tignish/features/security-id.png))</sub>

This is shown when the site is browsed via SSL/TLS (HTTPS) with a valid signed certificate. In order to implement that, you will need to purchase a certificate from a trusted certificate authority and configure your server to use that certificate.