# Image before URL in browser with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url

I am using asp.net with C# [3.5]. I want to display Image before my URL in browser, like IE and mozilla used to have. I want to display my custom image.

Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is currently the best way to get a favicon to display in all browsers that support Favicons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073/what-is-currently-the-best-way-to-get-a-favicon-to-display-in-all-browsers-that-s)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/23553354/410937 which provides a comprehensive answer as well. I like placing the favicon in the root of the domain as to not have to add the link information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're talking about a favicon.  Not all browsers recognize it, but most do.  You can add a link tag inside the head section of your HTML page with a link to the icon file:

```
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="http://www.example.com/myicon.ico"/>
```

More info here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Comment: It's forking in FF but not in IE, please help me how to display it in IE.
Thanks a ton for your response.

Comment: IE doesn't look for it as often as FF does. Add the link to your favorites (in newer versions of IE this checks for the icon), or try a hard-refresh (Ctrl-F5).

Comment: I tried it with IE 8, but all in vain ! :( 
I don't know why Microsoft is not looking for the enhancement of IE, it's not less with CS3.

Anyways, Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You mean a favicon?

Create a 16x16 pixel image and use this tool to convert it to an .ico file: http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/

Then place this line in your `<head>` section:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

Answer (score 2):

I do it like this in my asp.net page:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Content/images/favicon.ico") %>"/>
```

Works in all major browsers including IE 7 and 8. Haven't tested 6. Note that this is just like Ken's answer but a not-fully-qualified path is generated. The browser sees this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Content/images/favicon.ico"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean a [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)?