# How do you modify the generator-angular-fullstack favicon?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, yeoman

How do you modify the generator-angular-fullstack favicon?

I'm deploying the starter project https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack (the most popular yeoman generator).   This is a fullstack angularjs express framework.  By default it uses the yeoman guy as the favicon.  Is there a way to change it?

Anything helps.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either put your own `favicon.ico` in the root of your domain (accessible via e.g. `http://example.com/favicon.ico`) or link it in your HTML head:

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico" />
<link type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: of course, For some reason I thought I needed to register it with express.  Piece of cake.... thanks!

Comment: browsers are notorious for not updating the cached favicon. Try opening an incognito window and see if the new icon shows up.