# how to change the title bar image in IE browser

Tags: html, image

i have to change the internet explorer icon in the title with customized image not the one which appears on the address bar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is currently the best way to get a favicon to display in all browsers that support Favicons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073/what-is-currently-the-best-way-to-get-a-favicon-to-display-in-all-browsers-that-s)

Answer (score 4):

You can set your favicon by putting it in the root of your site or you can set it int he html like so

`<link rel="icon" href="http://www.quotes.co.uk/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">`

If your using photoshop this is a good plugin to create your flavicon:

http://www.telegraphics.com.au/sw/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a favicon.ico.

Answer (score 0):

The site icon file can be located anywhere in the site directory tree.

Because site icons are used both by Internet Explorer and Windows, only the .ICO file format is supported. If you change your site icon during development, you might need to clear the browser cache or rename the file to cause Internet Explorer to refresh its copy of the site icon.