# Static page does not show favicon

Tags: css, html, favicon

It has been four days since I have been trying to use my theoretical HTML and CSS knowledge to create a personal webpage.
Since I am still a beginner I did not host it and I am still under the process of creation.
I tried to create a favicon for my webpage so that it appears instead of the default "white paper with a fold on the top right."

Here is the code I have written:

```
     <head>
             <title>RAMYA VEMUGANTI</title>
             <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
     </head>
     <body>
            <div  id="header">
                <h1>Ramya Vemuganti</h1>
               <hr/>
            </div>
     </body>
```

Comment: Guessing it doesn't work. Does the file path in the source code link to the image ok?

Comment: Also what browser are you using?

Comment: The "white paper with a fold" .. isn't that what Google Chrome has. And I think Google Chrome only shows the favicon in the tab, not in the address bar. Is it showing in the tab?

Comment: @putvande Well my icon shows at neither the tab nor the address bar.So I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: @Jonnny I am using chrome and I have re-checked the image path and I am sure it is alright.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. `<link>` tag should be inside of `<head>` tag
2. You have two closing `<head>` tags
3. Your `<div>` content should by wrapped in a `<body>` tag BELOW the `<head>` tag
4. Make sure "favicon.ico" exists in the root location of your web server

and the  tag should look like:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: With a `.ico` you should have `type="image/x-icon"` instead of `type="image/png"`. The `type="image/png"` is only necessary with a favicon that is really a PNG (which is not supported by all browsers I think).

Comment: True - was a copy and paste from my current project. Can we verify which browsers that doesn't work in? This is a good answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073/what-is-currently-the-best-way-to-get-a-favicon-to-display-in-all-browsers-that

Comment: I know it isn't a good source but http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon has some info about browser support

Comment: I am currently using Chrome and I will edit the code in my question and clear the errors.Thank you @DeweyOx